# CAD Program "FiDES" Won't Launch on Laptop, 0xc000007b Error Thrown and Missing .dll Files

Tags: dll, cad

I'm trying to load a CAD program called FiDES on a workstation of mine running Win10 and the program won't launch.

It initially gave me errors for missing files MSVCP110.dll and MSVCR110.dll, which I tracked down, added, and **I don't think they are causing my current issue**.

When I launch FiDES I get a 0xc000007b error and I can't figure out why.

I've ran FiDES as an admin, uninstalled and reinstalled FiDES, unistalled and reinstalled up-to-date Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages, reinstalled Microsoft .NET framework, updated Windows updated my NVidia drivers, ran a check disc from the command prompt, and ran Dependency Walker.

Dependency Walker showed that the program was trying to find a few hundred API-MS-WIN files and a seemingly equal amount of EXT-MS-WIN files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/The-program-can-t-start-because-MSVCR110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer.html

Comment: This didn't help. Some actual guidance would be appreciated.